# Javafx good programming practices

Tags: java, javafx

The majority of my programming experience is in C++. I'm learning a lot of great features in Javafx but my biggest hurdle so far is whether or not I'm using good programming practices when writing applications in Javafx. Primarily, I was taught to keep the "main function" as clean as possible in C++, so it primarily contained my own class objects and their methods. Is this good practice in general when working in fx? i.e creating a number of classes outside of my main class, which contains the start method, and then adding the objects of those classes into the start method? Here is an example:

This program creates a BorderPane and places an HBox with two buttons at the top of it. I wrote the program in two different ways. One - all of the methods are in the Main class. Two - I created a separate class, which instantiates the HBox and then that is used in Main instead.

1.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        HBox hbox = addHBox();
        border.setTop(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene (border, 540,680);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public HBox addHBox()
    {
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(15,12,15,12));
        hb.setSpacing(10);
        hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button btnCurrent = new Button("Current");
        btnCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        btnCurrent.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 times; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");

        Button btnProjected = new Button("Projected");
        btnProjected.setPrefSize(100,20);
        btnProjected.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 times; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");

        hb.getChildren().addAll(btnCurrent,btnProjected);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return hb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

2.

I created a class Called Box:

```
public class Box extends HBox{


HBox hb = new HBox();
    public Box()
    {

        hb.setPadding(new Insets(15,12,15,12));
        hb.setSpacing(10);
        hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button btnCurrent = new Button("Current");
        btnCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        btnCurrent.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 times; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");

        Button btnProjected = new Button("Projected");
        btnProjected.setPrefSize(100,20);
        btnProjected.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 times; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");

        hb.getChildren().addAll(btnCurrent,btnProjected);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        getChildren().add(hb);
    }

}
```

And then use it in my main Function:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        Box hbox = new Box();
        border.setTop(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene (border, 540,680);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

That is my primary question, but also, if the second style (Creating your own classes and using them in your main class) is indeed the way to go, using my specific example, it places the HBox in an odd place and doesnt look right at all. What am I doing wrong by having the HBox instantiated in my Box Class' constructor and then adding it to my BorderPane in main?

I know that's a lot but if someone can give me some direction I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Though the second approach is better for reasons already stated in various answers, I would like to point out that one best practices is to create a separate `css file` for all your styling options.

Answer (score 0):

1)
In general it is good practice to introduce one class per view. If you are following that recommendation, your main function will remain clean in this example. There is no technological need to keep your main function clean, it's just a matter of organizing your code in a clean and maintainable way.

This would mean in this case create:

```
public class PrimaryView extends BorderPane {
    public PrimaryView() { .... }
}
```

Then in your Application:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene (new PrimaryView(), 540,680);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

2)
In your Box class you are adding a HBox to a HBox, that means you are creating 2 boxes and that is probably why it looks different. What you meant to do is probably:

```
public class Box extends HBox {

    public Box() {

        this.setPadding(new Insets(15,12,15,12));
        this.setSpacing(10);
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        ...

        // no need
        //getChildren().add(hb);
    }
 }
```

3)
One big advantage of using JavaFX is the [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) and the FXML with CSS files for styling. At first it is a bit complicated, but you will get used to it.

A really interesting framework is [AfterburnerFX](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx/) that comes with a good example. It is not easy to understand for beginners, but shows how you could organize your code and application. Focus on the binding of FXML and your View class.

Comment: Also consider that even with the one class per view pattern, your classes don't have to subclass a `Pane`. E.g. `public class Box { /* ... */ public Parent getView() { return ... ;} /* ...*/}`. I find this variation keeps my code cleaner than subclassing `Pane` (or other `Node`) classes.